# MacBook network stops showing Windows laptop if MacBook cover closed and re-opened

Tags: windows-7, networking, macbook

MacBook Pro is OS 10.9.5 with Ethernet connection to local router.
Windows laptop is Windows 7 Pro with Eth connection to same local router.

MacBook Network initially shows Windows laptop.
I close MacBook, come back, open MacBook:  no Windows laptop anymore.

I have to restart the Windows laptop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility the Macbook is winning the election to be master browser.

I had similar issues with SMB until I set one always-on machine in the building to always be the 'winner'

Try this on the Windows machine…

> To specify a computer as the preferred master browser, set the value of the IsDomainMaster entry to True.
>   This entry (data type Reg_SZ) appears in the following registry subkey:
>   `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services \Browser\Parameters`

Source - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959923.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396